# Why sinusoidally varying torque in induction machine not visible

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

We know that torque in an induction machine varies as \$k\times[\cos(2wt)+\cos(\beta)]\$ but we don't feel it. Why it's so?

Comment: Is that formula correct? I have not formally studied induction machines, but it was my understanding that the torque was proportional to the slip.

Comment: @mkeith, it is proportional to slip in a running, loaded induction motor. I didn't check the equation, but it looks *really* familiar. There are instantaneous fluctuations in torque based on when the poles of the rotor and the stator cross, though, but under any kind of load - including the rotor - they are usually inconsequential to anyone except the team that had to design the machine.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate that for 60 hz on an actual machine. Account for the rotational inertia of the rotor mass. Consider that momentum is like a bucket - if you add a drop and lose a drop 60 times a second, nobody is going to see the level change unless they are *really* looking for it.